# Timepicker not returning correct minutes

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am displaying my TimePicker in a dialog. Everything is displayed correctly, the timepicker responds and if I scroll/slide the ours and the minutes I get a correct time value when dismissing the dialog. The glitch happens when I make a single click on each field. If I click the hour field and set the hour via the on screen keyboard, the selector switches to minutes after I input my hours, and after inputting minutes, when dismissing the dialog I get the initial time the timepicker was set to instead of the minutes i selected/inputted.

I have tried

```
timeInput.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                    int minute) {

                Log.d("timepicker", Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));

            }

        });
```

and

```
int hour = timeInput.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timeInput.getCurrentMinute();
```

The hour value is always correct, the minute value is the problem, when it is scrolled to a desired value the change registers and the value is that of the selected, on the other hand if the minute is clicked and the value is enterd via on screen keyboard the change is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
timeInput.setCurrentHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
timeInput.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

just add it before listener, you are trying to pick value but before that you should set current time 
**i.e - SetCurrentTime >> ChangeTimeInPicker >> GetTimeFinally**